# Pattern Matching on `Data.Map` for Implementing `map`

Tags: haskell

I'm looking into how to implement `Data.Map#map` to apply a function `f` to each of a `Data.Map`'s values.

Let's consider `map'` in Haskell on a `List`:

```
map' :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
map' [] _     = []
map' (x:xs) f = f x : map' xs f
```

Note that I can pattern match on `(x:xs)` to recursively call `map' xs f`.

How can I pattern match to recursively apply `f` to each of `Data.Map`'s values?

Comment: `Data.Map`, by not exporting constructors, is specifically designed to prevent you from doing this.

Comment: Or, you could use [ViewPatterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns).

Comment: why does it prevent people from doing this?

Comment: So you can't do foolish things like manually construct unbalanced or mis-ordered trees. Is something wrong with just using `fmap`?  Notice `Map` is an instance of many useful type classes.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson - I was trying to do this LYAH exercise: `Try figuring out how Map k is made an instance of Functor by yourself!`. I suppose that I don't need to implement `Data.Map#map` in order to do it, yea?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I think the excercise is meant to encourage you to think about it, rather than actually have you implement it. For the purposes of the excercise you can think of map as if it was `type Map k a = [(k,a)]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While you can't write this yourself since Data.Map doesn't export constructors, we can cheat a little.

Specifically, if we pull up the source on [github](https://github.com/haskell/containers/blob/master/Data/Map/Base.hs) we can poke around a bit to see how exactly `fmap` is implemented.

The actual definition of `Map` is surprisingly simple

```
-- Ignore the !'s and UNPACK, it's telling GHC to do some clever things
-- with how strict the constructors are.
data Map k a  = Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !k a !(Map k a) !(Map k a)
              | Tip
```

So a `Map` is either empty, `Tip`, or a branch, `Bin`, with a key, value, size, and two subchildren.

`Size` is also defined quite simply :)

```
type Size = Int
```

Now, on to the `Functor` instance! The precise definition is

```
instance Functor (Map k) where
  fmap f m = map f m
```

Now `map` is exactly what you would expect it to be

```
map :: (a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
map _ Tip = Tip
map f (Bin sx kx x l r) = Bin sx kx (f x) (map f l) (map f r)
```

All we do is modify the value with `f` and then recurse. Trivial :)

Balancing and other tomfoolery don't need to happen here since we're only modifying the values in the tree, not the structure or keys on which it's ordered.

Now, since it'd defeat the point of the problem if you didn't write some code, why don't you implement `fmap` for a similar, simpler, structure

```
 data BinTree a = Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
                | Leaf
```

Answer (score 3):

@jozefg's answer is very good.  Do that.  But every so often you really do want to break down data abstractions such as for `Data.Map.Map`, and it is in fact possible.  You can use Template Haskell to access a module's internals, and the `lens` package actually provides everything that's necessary to accomplish it.  I'm presenting this without commentary, because most of the time this is not what you should do.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module M where

import Data.Map as Map
import Control.Lens.TH
import Control.Lens

$(makePrisms ''Map)

mymap :: (a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
mymap f inmap
    | Just () <- inmap ^? _Tip = review _Tip ()
    | Just (sz,k,a,l,r) <- inmap ^? _Bin =
        review _Bin (sz,k, f a, mymap f l, mymap f r)
```